# ImageMagick image with section with transparency disapears

Tags: imagemagick, png, transparency, gif

I am having trouble with images that has part of the image transparent to create a gif out of it. I am currently using the following command/flags:

> convert -dispose previous -delay 10 -loop 0 -alpha opaque -transparent algaPos00* test.gif
> I have tried the following flags for alpha:
> opaque, transparent, on, off
> and what I get,

1. is a gif with the external ring not transparent at all (and quite different to the original image)
2. a gif without the external ring
3. a completely transparent gif
   here is the concerning image:
   [image]

any help would be appreciated

PS. the output could be 'not transparent' but would like to keep the 'lightish' color of it, as when I do opaque, the color is way stronger and ungly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the question. What exactly are you trying to do with the transparency and colors in Imagemagick?  I note that you cannot go from a single PNG image to an animated GIF. You only have one frame. You could repeat the frame but it would not look animated. You might do

`convert image.png +dither -colors 256 image.gif`

[image]

Is that close to what you want.  I note that PNG supports 8-bit transparency, but GIF only supports binary transparency (on or off).  So your partially transparent outer ring can only be opaque or fully transparent.

Comment: I simply uploaded one as example, as this keeps the same issue I am facing. when I am trying to do the gif (with several images). and you answered me with the second part of your comment, that accept fully or opaque transparency, thanks.